# Some routes are returning 404 not found after Breeze install on Laravel

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-10, laravel-breeze

I've recently tried to get into Laravel and installed Laravel 10 (just on Lamp as I can't get Docker to work on Windows or Ubuntu) and the welcome page loads fine. I've then tried to add Breeze and the welcome page now displays the login and register buttons top right but when I click on them I just get a 404 not found. Breeze has also added /dashboard to web.php in routes and this also returns a 404.

This is all new to me and I'm slowly losing the will to live! I'm not sure what's going wrong. Has anyone got any suggestions, please?

I've checked the routes exist and routes/web.php is requiring auth.php which contains those routes. Everything seems to have been populated correctly. Here is the code so far...

routes/web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

routes.auth.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationPromptController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordResetLinkController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerifyEmailController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('register');

    Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('login');

    Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('password.request');

    Route::post('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
                ->name('password.email');

    Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('password.reset');

    Route::post('reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
                ->name('password.store');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('verify-email', EmailVerificationPromptController::class)
                ->name('verification.notice');

    Route::get('verify-email/{id}/{hash}', VerifyEmailController::class)
                ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
                ->name('verification.verify');

    Route::post('email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('throttle:6,1')
                ->name('verification.send');

    Route::get('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'show'])
                ->name('password.confirm');

    Route::post('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'store']);

    Route::put('password', [PasswordController::class, 'update'])->name('password.update');

    Route::post('logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
                ->name('logout');
});
```

resources/views/welcome.blade.php (snippet)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div class="relative sm:flex sm:justify-center sm:items-center min-h-screen bg-dots-darker bg-center bg-gray-100 dark:bg-dots-lighter dark:bg-gray-900 selection:bg-red-500 selection:text-white">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="sm:fixed sm:top-0 sm:right-0 p-6 text-right z-10">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/dashboard') }}" class="font-semibold text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white focus:outline focus:outline-2 focus:rounded-sm focus:outline-red-500">Dashboard</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="font-semibold text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white focus:outline focus:outline-2 focus:rounded-sm focus:outline-red-500">Log in</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="ml-4 font-semibold text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white focus:outline focus:outline-2 focus:rounded-sm focus:outline-red-500">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif
```

views/auth/register.blade.php

```
<x-guest-layout>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
        @csrf

        <!-- Name -->
        <div>
            <x-input-label for="name" :value="__('Name')" />
            <x-text-input id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="name" :value="old('name')" required autofocus autocomplete="name" />
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('name')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <!-- Email Address -->
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-input-label for="email" :value="__('Email')" />
            <x-text-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" :value="old('email')" required autocomplete="username" />
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('email')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <!-- Password -->
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-input-label for="password" :value="__('Password')" />

            <x-text-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full"
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            required autocomplete="new-password" />

            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <!-- Confirm Password -->
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-input-label for="password_confirmation" :value="__('Confirm Password')" />

            <x-text-input id="password_confirmation" class="block mt-1 w-full"
                            type="password"
                            name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password" />

            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password_confirmation')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
            <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-gray-100 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800" href="{{ route('login') }}">
                {{ __('Already registered?') }}
            </a>

            <x-primary-button class="ms-4">
                {{ __('Register') }}
            </x-primary-button>
        </div>
    </form>
</x-guest-layout>
```

php artisan route:list

> GET|HEAD  / .......................................................................................................................................
> POST      _ignition/execute-solution ................................ ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController
> GET|HEAD  _ignition/health-check ............................................ ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController
> POST      _ignition/update-config ......................................... ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController
> GET|HEAD  api/user ................................................................................................................................
> GET|HEAD  confirm-password ............................................................. password.confirm › Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController@show
> POST      confirm-password ............................................................................... Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController@store
> GET|HEAD  dashboard ..................................................................................................................... dashboard
> POST      email/verification-notification .................................. verification.send › Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController@store
> GET|HEAD  forgot-password .............................................................. password.request › Auth\PasswordResetLinkController@create
> POST      forgot-password ................................................................. password.email › Auth\PasswordResetLinkController@store
> GET|HEAD  login ................................................................................ login › Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@create
> POST      login ......................................................................................... Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@store
> POST      logout ............................................................................. logout › Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@destroy
> PUT       password ............................................................................... password.update › Auth\PasswordController@update
> GET|HEAD  profile ........................................................................................... profile.edit › ProfileController@edit
> PATCH     profile ....................................................................................... profile.update › ProfileController@update
> DELETE    profile ..................................................................................... profile.destroy › ProfileController@destroy
> GET|HEAD  register ................................................................................ register › Auth\RegisteredUserController@create
> POST      register ............................................................................................ Auth\RegisteredUserController@store
> POST      reset-password ........................................................................ password.store › Auth\NewPasswordController@store
> GET|HEAD  reset-password/{token} ............................................................... password.reset › Auth\NewPasswordController@create
> GET|HEAD  sanctum/csrf-cookie ................................................... sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
> GET|HEAD  verify-email ............................................................... verification.notice › Auth\EmailVerificationPromptController
> GET|HEAD  verify-email/{id}/{hash} ............................................................... verification.verify › Auth\VerifyEmailController

```
                                                                                                                              Showing [25] routes
```

Comment: Is it a Laravel 404, or a webserver 404? What does `php artisan route:list` show?

Comment: Did you run `php artisan route:clear` by any chance? Are you sure you're not already logged in either? Since the routes are behind the `guest` middleware (try clearing cookies).

Did you also troubleshoot for a webserver configuration issue? (Just add a  simple get route with a `die('ok');` in it)

Comment: @ceejayoz It's a webserver 404. I've added the output of route:list to the question and it all looks OK. I'm assuming that means it's something to do with the way I've setup virtualhost on apache?

Comment: @Tofandel I don't believe I did. I'm yet to be able to login and have tried clearing cookies/opening in incognito. I've created a new get route and still 404 (webserver not Laravel)

Comment: @JayMason Yeah, if it's a webserver 404, you'll want to be looking there. If it's Apache, make sure it's set up to permit the `public/.htaccess` to set rules.